# Unexpected null values after custom deserialization

Tags: java, serialization

I have the following class design. My engine attribute is coming as null each time,even though I have read its value from `readObject`

```
public class Car implements Serializable {

    private int regId;
    transient Engine e;


private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) {
        try {
            oos.defaultWriteObject();
            oos.writeInt(e.horsePower);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream oxos) {
        try {    
            oxos.defaultReadObject();
            Engine e = new Engine(oxos.readInt());              

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
}

public class Engine  {    
        int horsePower;    
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `Engine e` is a local variable in your read method. You may want to call `this.e` instead since this.e refeers to the class variable that starts being null.

Comment: Fixed your title. readObject() isn't 'returning null values' at all. Your own code is doing that because of a scoping bug.

Answer (score 4):

You don't assign the field `e` -- it's being shadowed by the local variable you create with `Engine e = new Engine(oxos.readInt());`.